# scene.js:68 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scene')

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to load an animated model(.glb) in three.js but I get the above error.
If I paste the Load animated model function in the main method then it works but if I use it in a seperate class then it doesn't work anymore. Also the LoadStaticModel function does work but not the animated function. Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
class CharacterControllerInput{
   mixers = [];
   scene;
  constructor(scene){
    this.scene = scene;
    this.LoadAnimatedModel();
  }

   LoadAnimatedModel(scene){
    this.scene = scene;

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/docs/BeterWerktDit.glb', function ( gltf ) {

      gltf.scene.traverse( function ( object ) {

        if ( object.isMesh ) object.castShadow = true;

      } );


      const model1 =  SkeletonUtils.clone( gltf.scene );


      const mixer1 = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model1 );


      mixer1.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] ).play(); 

      
      this.scene.add( model1);
      this.mixers.push( mixer1);

      render();

    } );
  }
```

Here is an abbreviated version of the class where I instantiate the Class.

```
class Scene{

  constructor(){
    this.main();
  }
    main(){

    const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');


    const renderer =  new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, antialias: true});


    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    




      this.character = new CharacterControllerInput(scene);
    render();

       function render(){

        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  
        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  
        const delta = clock.getDelta();
        for (const mixer of mixers) mixer.update(delta);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render)
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
};

let _APP = null;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  _APP = new Scene();
});
```

Comment: What is `gltf`?

Comment: gltf is a file format for 3d models

Comment: Somewhere you have an `undefined` object, which you try to read `.scene` from. Presumably this is your `gltf` object.

Comment: I logged gltf, model1 and mixer1 in the console and none of them are 'undefined'. Also the exact same function with the same model works in the main method. So I don't know what in the code is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error. The problem was that I used this.scene in the callback function. So this. refers to the callback function.

The code below works:

```
class CharacterControllerInput {
  scene;
  constructor(scene, mixers) {
    this.scene = scene;
    this.mixers = mixers;
    this.LoadAnimatedModel();
  }

  _init() {
    this.LoadAnimatedModel();
  }

  LoadAnimatedModel() {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    const scene = this.scene;
    const mixers = this.mixers;

    loader.load('http://127.0.0.1:3000/docs/BeterWerktDit.glb', function (gltf) {

      gltf.scene.traverse(function (object) {

        if (object.isMesh) object.castShadow = true;

      });

      const model = SkeletonUtils.clone(gltf.scene);


      const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);

      mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();

      scene.add(model);
      mixers.push(mixer);


    });
  }
```